# memcpy character pointer array

Tags: c

```
char **gbuffer = NULL;
void dump(char **buffer)
{
    int i;
    buffer = realloc(buffer, 50 *sizeof(char **));

    for(i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
    {
      buffer[i] = malloc(50 *sizeof(char));
      buffer[i] = gbuffer[i];
    }

    printf("string is %s\n", buffer[0]);  //able to access here
}
int main()
{
    char **buffer = NULL;

    gbuffer = realloc(gbuffer, 50 *sizeof(char **));
    int i;
    for(i =0 ;i < 10; i++)
    {
      gbuffer[i] = malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
      strcpy(gbuffer[i], "ashish");
    }

    dump(buffer);
    printf(" global string is %s\n", gbuffer[0]);
    printf("string is %s\n", buffer[0]);            //not able to access this value
    return 0;
}
```

I am able to access buffer in dump() but unable to access variable in main.
How can I access buffer[0] in main()?
I have attached pseudo-code.

Comment: does this even compile?

Comment: You didn't allocate any memory for your `buffer`.

Comment: I know this, i just want to know how can i access the value of buffer I am new to C

Comment: `memcopy(&buffer, &gbuffer, sizeof(gbuffer));` is same as `buffer = gbuffer;`

Comment: I have attached pseudo code please see it.and help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code in `main` that allocates `gbuffer` works correctly.  It looks like your function `dump` is trying to do the same thing.  It looks like, within `dump`, it correctly allocates `buffer`.  But then, finally, back in `main`, `buffer` is improper.

That's because `dump` allocates memory and stores it in `dump`'s copy of the `buffer` pointer, but it doesn't get propagated back to `main`.

(This is a very common problem.  By rights I shouldn't answer it; I should point you to one of the many hundreds of duplicate questions.)

One way to fix it is to have `dump` return the new value of `buffer`.  I have also changed `dump`'s name, since it does much more than just dump the buffer it's passed.  I have also fixed several other problems, which I'll explain later.

```
char **gbuffer = NULL;

char ** reallocate_and_dump(char **buffer)
{
    int i;
    buffer = realloc(buffer, 50 * sizeof(char *));

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      buffer[i] = malloc(50);
      strcpy(buffer[i], gbuffer[i]);
    }

    printf("string is %s\n", buffer[0]);

    return buffer;
}

int main()
{
    char **buffer = NULL;

    gbuffer = realloc(gbuffer, 50 * sizeof(char *));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      gbuffer[i] = malloc(50);
      strcpy(gbuffer[i], "ashish");
    }

    buffer = reallocate_and_dump(buffer);
    printf(" global string is %s\n", gbuffer[0]);
    printf("string is %s\n", buffer[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

You were saying things like `buffer = realloc(buffer, 50 * sizeof(char **))`, but that's not quite right.  `buffer` holds 50 `char *`'s.  So you want `buffer = realloc(buffer, 50 * sizeof(char *))`.

You were saying things like `buffer[i] =  malloc(50 * sizeof(char))`, but multiplying by `sizeof(char)` is unnecessary, because `sizeof(char)` is, by definition, exactly 1.  So I have changed those to `buffer[i] = malloc(50)`.

You had the pair of lines

```
buffer[i] = malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
buffer[i] = gbuffer[i];
```

Here you allocate 50 bytes of memory and then immediately waste it by overwriting the pointer with a different pointer out of the `gbuffer` array.  This is confusing and probably not what you want.  I have replaced this with

```
buffer[i] = malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
strcpy(buffer[i], gbuffer[i]);
```

which I think makes more sense.

---

The other possibility, the other way to have `reallocate_and_dump` update and return the pointer it's handed, is to have it accept a pointer to that pointer.  But since the pointer it's handed is already a two-level pointer, we end up with a three-level pointer, and I don't know about you, but three-level pointers have a tendency to make my head explode.  Nevertheless, here's what that code looks like:

```
void reallocate_and_dump_2(char ***buffer_pointer)
{
    int i;
    char **buffer = *buffer_pointer;

    buffer = realloc(buffer, 50 * sizeof(char *));

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      buffer[i] = malloc(50);
      strcpy(buffer[i], gbuffer[i]);
    }

    printf("string is %s\n", buffer[0]);

    *buffer_pointer = buffer;
}

int main()
{
    char **buffer = NULL;

    gbuffer = realloc(gbuffer, 50 * sizeof(char *));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      gbuffer[i] =  malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
      strcpy(gbuffer[i], "ashish");
    }

    reallocate_and_dump_2(&buffer);
    printf(" global string is %s\n", gbuffer[0]);
    printf("string is %s\n", buffer[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , It was useful